# Использование array_filter

Tags: php

Есть определённый массив и я хочу его отфильтровать по определённым ключам.
Для этого использую встроенную в php функцию для работы с массивами `array_filter`. Но можно ли так делать как делаю я:

```
$anyArray = [
    ...
];
$anyArray = array_filter($anyArray, function ($a) {
    return $a['category'] == 'receive' && $a['account'] !== '';
});
```

Да, это работает, но правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: все правильно, а что вызывает сомнения?

Comment: Можно, а в чем проблема? Ошибки  или не работает, что - то?

Comment: Просто я обыватель в php и нигде не видел такое использование :)